# How to update a datastore entity with Objectify?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I use the Google App Engine datastore and I need to update one my entities which has been saved on it (I use the Objectify framework to perform operations on the datastore).
However, I only need to update one field of the entity.
For now I load (calling `load()`) the entity, use a getter/setter to modify the field and then call `save()` to persist it. I am sure there is a better way. What is the preferred method to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal way.

I guess you're looking for SQL-like UPDATE? Google Datastore doesn't have such things. Update and Insert are same operation - you're putting an Entity for a key.

See docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Updating_an_entity

Comment: It needs to be mentioned that to do an update safely, the load/save must be performed in a transaction.

Comment: yes, that's a good idea. or catch ConcurrentModificationException exception, and do some domain/code specific workaround

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. However, are transactions required whenever I want to update something? For instance, let's say I have a Book entity and a `int readings` field which increments each time a get() operation has been performed on the book. How could that lead to ConcurrentModification Exception?

Comment: if other request made same update to db, for example. maybe user clicked button twice, maybe because some error in app logic. many possible ways why entity got updated after initial query. transaction are useful if you have few entities to update, it doesn't lock db, and you can get same exception still

Comment: This is not correct. If you perform a write outside of a transaction, you will not see CME - the datastore hides any contention from you. It means "write this data no matter what", which could step on other writes that happened between load & save. You need a transaction. Also, incrementing counters is a whole study by itself, and too long a subject for this comment field.

Comment: oh, seem that you're right. i remembered such exception w/o transaction, but maybe i'm wrong, was too long ago. as I see official docs suggest to always use transaction to get CME